# Help on placing a LiPo in casing

Tags: battery, pi-pico, safety

I'm planning on building a portable Pico Prototyping box using a Pimoroni [Pico LiPo](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/pimoroni-pico-lipo?variant=39335427080275) and a [LiPo battery](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/lipo-battery-pack?variant=20429082055). My question is if you put all of the parts in a case, is electrical shielding needed between the battery and the PCB of the Pico? Another question: what is the best way to make the LiPo shock proof, or will it not explode if I drop it in a plastic case. If there is no good way to protect it, I'll use the [plastic casing LiPo](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/galleon-400mah-battery?variant=40061068673107).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question: no, electrical shielding is generally not needed. The exterior shell of LiPo batteries is not conductive. The only scenario I can think of where some sort of shielding may be needed is if your battery (for some reason) has completely exposed terminals.

For your second question: no, you also don't need an intricate casing for the battery. A LiPo won't explode unless it is bent or punctured, and to puncture a LiPo purely from the shock of falling requires more force than it will ever experience being in a plastic case (most likely).

TL;DR: Unless you have some critical "industrial-like" application where the LiPo will be under constant strain, no, you don't need anything more than a simple case.